# Visual Studio 2015 Express: Don't jump to next statement, when breaking the program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

In Visual Studio, when you break (or pause) a program, the editor always shows me, what statement would be the next when I'm resuming and jumps right to it. This is everytime(?) a line which consumes most of the time.

In my case this is SwapBuffers(window) from GLFW.

What I want now, is that he still marks it, but he shouldnt jump away from where I am because it's really annoying. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but possibly use "Step Over" instead of "Step In" - (F10 key)? This will execute current marked statement in one step and move to the next one in the current scope.

Comment: No, my point was that the editor jumped to this statement right when i hit the "pause" button. And I don't want him to jump anywhere or even open another file to jump to this point.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to thwart the very purpose of the debugger. Can you try explaining what you're trying to accomplish more clearly? Suppose one class calls another class (in another file). How would the editor show you what statement is next without opening that file, much less jumping to it?

Comment: All I want is that he doesn't jump away from where I'm working.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut for pausing execution is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

The keyboard shortcut for navigating back to the previous position is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (use the minus sign which is **not** on the numeric keypad).

So you can just hit these both of these shortcuts manually, or you can use something like [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to program your own shortcut which sends both of them automatically, with a small delay between them.

Answer (score 1):

"[Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx)" option might help - it always skips foreign code in debug mode.

> feature that steps over system, framework, and other non-user calls and collapses those calls in the call stack windows

[image]

Comment: The option where he stops is my code. And I don't want to skip code, just not that he forces me to look at the spot he stopped. I'm talking about a manual break here by using the pause button, not using break points.

Comment: The pause button pauses on the statement which is being executed, it just happens to be in the code you're not interested in - that's how it works, there's nothing you can do about that. You could "Step out" until you get back to the code you're interested in, or you could use "back" (Navigate Backward, `ctrl` + `-`) button to return to the previously viewed source file.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an option you can turn off.

If you're using Visual Studio, pull the annoying tab out and dock it to one side.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx